# filepath Base on windows not working after cross compilation (Golang)

Tags: go, filepath

If I have a path on linux/OSX such as `filepath := /Users/jamesbond/some/where/file.txt`

then I can do

`name := path.Base(filepath)`

and name will be `file.txt`

however on windows this does not work. The returned value of name is still `/Users/jamesbond/some/where/file.txt`

I guess I can see why, as the function base has

```
    for len(path) > 0 && path[len(path)-1] == '/' {
        path = path[0 : len(path)-1]
    }
```

i.e its clearly really only setup for linux/OSX style file paths.

I am cross compiling from OSX for windows. I guess that the library on windows has the corect `/` in the SDK, but how can I handle this regardless of OS? Is there a way to convert or something before, then use `Base` function?

What would be the recommended way to write this code once and it work on all OSes?

Comment: The `filepath` packages has functions for normalizing paths: Do [`FromSlash`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#FromSlash) and [`ToSlash`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#ToSlash) not do what you need?

Comment: filepath uses os.IsPathSeparator. Where did you find that code? https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.1:src/path/filepath/path.go;l=549

Comment: Looks like you are using the `path` package. Use the `filepath` package